# How specify parameter's format in Nelmio ApiDocBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7, nelmioapidocbundle

I use `input` property of `@ApiDoc` annotation for specifieng of parameters of my api that are form's fields.

```
 * @ApiDoc(
 *      section="User",
 *      resource=true,
 *      input={
 *          "class"="Nik\UserBundle\Form\UserType",
 *      },
 *     ....
```

`data_class` of form is a entity that have constraint validation for properties.

I expect that nelmio api doc specify parameter format as validation constraints of entity, but format are empty.

[image]

How can i specify parameter formats in nelmio ApiDocBundle?

---

**EDIT**:
maybe i write a bad question.

we can specify parsers for `input` & `output`, if we no specify parser for these, it call all parser for `input` & `output`, then all parser are called for `UserType`.

`nelmio` have a parser named [ValidationParser](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/Parser/ValidationParser.php) that have a method named [parseConstraint](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/Parser/ValidationParser.php#L183) that set `format` for input & output, but this method is not called for my document, why?

Comment: How did you specify **description** per each field? I cannot find any reliable.

Comment: Ok, I've found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810982/1335142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i submit a pull request that use validation metadata for `format` property.

you can see this `PR` [here](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/pull/793)

Answer (score 6):

Format column is designed only for `datetime`, `date` and `choice` types.

For `datetime` and `date` it represents the date format like `Y-m-d H:i:s` and the array of choices for `choice`.

I haven't found any documentation about it, so I had to look through the source code. This is [FormTypeParser](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/2.x/Parser/FormTypeParser.php#L241) class, the place where `FormType` is actually parsed and and you can see how format field is set.

In [FormTypeParserTest](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/2.x/Tests/Parser/FormTypeParserTest.php#L326) class you can see how to use it. Just pass the string parameter with `format` name for one of the available types and the parser will handle it.

**UPDATE:** You are to define your constrains inside your `FormType` class.

For example:

```
class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @Assert\Length(min="10", max="255")
     * @Assert\Regex("/^[^<>]+$/i")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @Assert\Length(min="10", max="255")
     * @Assert\Regex("/^[^<>]+$/i")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    private $created;

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

will be parsed into:

[image]

`ValidationParser` in 
[doParse()](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/2.x/Parser/ValidationParser.php#L100) method finds all constrains defined in your `FormType` class and then executes `parseConstraint()` method for each of them.

You can also use `FormTypeParser` as I described above. For example:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('created', 'date', array('label' => 'Created', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
        ->add('color', 'choice', array('label' => 'Color', 'choices' => array('grey' => '#CCCCCC', 'red' => '#FF0000')))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

will be parsed as:

[image]

Hope it helps now!

Comment: thank you, it's works, but in first way, i force redefine all entity properties in form type is not usefull and in second way, i can not specify format for other fields as text

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) you can specify filter in annotation like it done documentation example.

Here part of this example:

```
/**
 * This is the documentation description of your method, it will appear
 * on a specific pane. It will read all the text until the first
 * annotation.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=true,
 *  description="This is a description of your API method",
 *  filters={
 *      {"name"="a-filter", "dataType"="integer"},
 *      {"name"="another-filter", "dataType"="string", "pattern"="(foo|bar) ASC|DESC"}
 *  }
 * )
 */
public function getAction()
{
}
```

Comment: i no want write filters by hand, i will use my form as input and nelmio read form & entity validations and use those as format for parameters