# set Nelmio ApiDoc return parameter description

Tags: symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

On the ApiDoc for our controller we have specified the output response object and now we see a list of all the parameters that get returned.
[image: Output Params]
How do we provide values for the version and/or description fields on this list?

I have tried adding `@ApiDoc(description="text")` to the response object's parameters but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stepped through the ApiDocBundle today and see that Description comes from the comment on the model property or method with @VirtualProperty.

For example:

```
/**
 * This text will be displayed as the response property's description
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 * @JMS\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'>")
 */
protected $dateTimeProperty;
```

or

```
/**
 * VirtualProperty comment
 *
 * @JMS\Type("integer")
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty()
 * @return integer
 */
public function getVirtualProperty()
{
    return $this->someFunc();
}
```

The same applies to the all comments on the controller method.

[image: The result of the above ^]

Comment: Did you figure out how to add `version` to a separate property?

Answer (score 1):

This is a working API method from one of my projects:

```
/**
     * Get an extended FB token given a normal access_token
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  resource=true,
     *  requirements={
     *      {
     *          "name"="access_token",
     *          "dataType"="string",
     *          "description"="The FB access token",
     *          "version" = "1.0"
     *      }
     *  },
     *  views = { "facebook" }
     * )
     * @Get("/extend/token/{access_token}", name="get_extend_fb_token", options={ "method_prefix" = false }, defaults={"_format"="json"})
     */
    public function getExtendTokenAction(Request $request, $access_token)
    {
        //...
    }
```

All APIDoc parameters that get returned are grouped under "requirements".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used nelmioApiDoc but looking at the documentation for it, using `description="text"` in the annotation section seems correct. Have you tried clearing you cache:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Not sure if it is related.

This [section describes how versioning objects](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/other-bundle-annotations.html#versioning-objects) is used, and looks like you have to use `@Until("x.x.x")` and `@Since("x.x")` in your JMSSerializerBundle classes. [See this link](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#versioning-objects).